# How to create a database and insert into it from activities in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database question for you on android.

On initial startup of my application, i call for a JSON file from my server,  that is returned to me and from this JSON file i can recreate an array list of objects using GSON.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

ArrayList<Spot> spots = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(),new TypeToken<List<Spot>>() {}.getType());
```

Now that i have this arraylist, i want to input all this into a database. All the above is achieved in my splash activity.

What i need is some help with the creation of the database, and then how to input data into it, the examples online are quite confusing and all disimilar

Answer (score 0):

Android Notepad tutorial on Android developers site will help you to solve the problem. All you need is patience. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think below helper class can help you

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class EventDataSQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Table name
    public static final String TABLE = "events";
    // Columns
    public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";

    public EventDataSQLHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "create table " + TABLE + "( " + BaseColumns._ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + TIME + " integer, "
                + TITLE + " text not null);";
        Log.d("EventsData", "onCreate: " + sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion >= newVersion)
            return;
        String sql = null;
        if (oldVersion == 1)
            sql = "alter table " + TABLE + " add note text;";
        if (oldVersion == 2)
            sql = "";
        Log.d("EventsData", "onUpgrade  : " + sql);
        if (sql != null)
            db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i go about inserting data from an activity into the database now with this?